# Grid view height/width formula

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, math

I have an rectangle area that I want to fit a varing amount of sqaure items. Here is an image to help with the problem.

[image]

Could anyone help me with a formular to calculate the width/height(Bw/Bh) of the items?

I tried √(WxH/N).

But with an example of W = 1400, H = 380, N = 16 that gave me 182. But 1400/182 only gives 7.7 boxes width and 2.08 high (Multiplied I get my 16, but I need them to fit within the area).

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Getting closer I think what I really need to know is based around the aspect ratio and how to work out a grid that accommodate the items. E.g. 16 boxes below in 254 x 133 is 6 by 3.

[image]

EDIT:

I've now wrote the following code to work out the grid (javascript). Problem is that it is using a trail and error method.

```
var W = 254,
    H = 133,
    N = 16,
    Bh = H;

while( ((Math.floor(W/Bh)) * (Math.floor(H/Bh))) < N ){
    Bh--;            
}

alert('Columns: '+Math.floor(W/Bh)+', Rows: '+Math.floor(H/Bh)+', Bow width: '+(Bh) );
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GVp4X/ to test the code. I'm still certain there is a better way though.

Comment: Why is 7.7 bad? Why would you think that a certain number of boxes would *always* fit nicely in any rectangle?

Comment: Should have said that I'm not bothered if there is space left over, there nearly always will be, but I can centre the boxes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define some meaningful constraint for the aspect ratio of the (small) boxes. For example, you can always divide the big box into N parts vertically or horizontally, but I don't think that is what you want to do. And for prime numbers N, this is the only thing you can do. Would it be okay to add "padding" of empty boxes in this case?

EDIT:

If N is reasonably small, you can just loop through all possible, w, the numbers of boxes per row and minimize some suitable penalty function for wrong aspect ratio and number of unused boxes. Here's an example (in Matlab code)

```
N = 123;
target_aspect = 4/3;
W = 80;
H = 60;

min_F = inf;
for w=1:N,
   h = ceil(N/w);
   Bh = H/h;
   Bw = W/w;

   padding = h*w-N;
   aspect = Bw / Bh;

   %# The penalty function to minimize
   F = abs(aspect-target_aspect) + padding * 0.05;

   if F < min_F,
       min_F = F;
       best_w = w;        
   end
end
```

EDIT2:

It is also possible to do this with a fixed aspect ratio if empty space ("ypadding") is allowed, for example, at the bottom margin. Then the loop body could be something like

```
Bw = W/w;
Bh = Bw/aspect;
h = floor(H/Bh);

n = w*h;

if n >= N,
   ypadding = H-Bh*h;
   padding = h*w-N;

   %# penalty function
   F = (ypadding/Bh)*0.3 + (padding / w)*0.2

   if F < min_F,
      min_F = F;
      best_w = w;
   end        
end
```

In this case the search range for w can also be reduced by solving a quadratic problem.

Comment: Similar to what I came up with. But a bit better if you need to take the target aspect + padding into consideration. Thanks for your time & definitely worth a vote up. Cheers